# Failed to resolve: lifecycle-runtime-2.2.0

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I'm trying to add [android-youtube-player](https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player) to my android project. When I add it to the gradle dependencies, gradle sync finishes with this warning:

```
Failed to resolve: lifecycle-runtime-2.2.0
```

Trying to run the app produces the following error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find recyclerview-1.1.0.jar (androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/recyclerview/recyclerview/1.1.0/recyclerview-1.1.0.jar
   > Could not find lifecycle-runtime-2.2.0.jar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.2.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/lifecycle/lifecycle-runtime/2.2.0/lifecycle-runtime-2.2.0.jar
```

My build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.****.********"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0'
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.2.0"
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'

    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'

    implementation 'com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer:core:10.0.5'
}
```

It has no problems without `implementation 'com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer:core:10.0.5'`

I have tried cleaning the project and deleting .gradle folder, but it hasn't helped. Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Make sure you have `google()` in your `repositories` closures in the top-level `build.gradle` file.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have `allprojects {repositories {google()  jcenter()}}` in top level build.gradle.

Comment: Hmmm... for some reason, your project is trying to pull in JAR files, and both of those are AAR files. And [the POM file for that YouTube library](https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/pierfrancescosoffritti/androidyoutubeplayer/core/10.0.5/:core-10.0.5.pom) is not requesting `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime` and it is requesting a different version of the `RecyclerView` artifact. You might try adding `implementation` lines in your module's `build.gradle` for those two artifacts and see if Gradle will resolve them to AARs as it is supposed to.

Comment: @CommonsWare I tried adding `RecyclerView` and `lifecycle-runtime` `implementation` lines but the same error appeared. Thanks anyway.

Comment: OK, now try adding `@aar` to the end of each (e.g., `implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0@aar"`) and see if that helps.

Comment: @CommonsWare It didn't quite help, but i tried replacing `google()` with `maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }` in `repositories` and it worked! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

if all reps are true
then from android studio files invalidate cache and restart

solve the problem for me